# Titlesec package removes indents from section headers

Tags: sectioning, indentation, titlesec

For my text document with the `book` class I start each new chapter with an abstract. The format of this abstract section is designed such that the abstract header is indented with respect to the abstract text, like:

```
   Abstract
Insert text here
```

The abstract is designed as an environment with the `NewDocumentEnvironment` command.

However when the `titlesec` package is included in the document, the indent of the abstract header is removed.

How can I keep the indent in the abstract header, or how can I tell the `titlesec` package to not touch the section header formatting?

The `titlesec` package is included because I want to customize the chapter title (and only the chapter titles).

A MWE (toggle the `titlesec` package to check the indentation):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xparse} 
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters


\NewDocumentEnvironment{ChapterAbstract}{}
    {
        % Change the margins of the abstract relative to the regular text
        \begin{adjustwidth}{15pt}{15pt} 
        \nointerlineskip\leavevmode % Necessary addition due to the macro expansion of adjustwidth. Solves the 'missing item' error
        \section*{\indent\scshape\large abstract} % Smallcaps abstract title in \large fontsize with an indentation
        \itshape
    }
    {
        \end{adjustwidth}
    }

    \begin{document}


    \chapter{Chapter title test here}
    \begin{ChapterAbstract}
    \blindtext
    \end{ChapterAbstract}

    \section{Test section}
    \blindtext
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I have no problem with this code. Are you sure the indent disappears with just this code?

Comment: If I toggle the titlesec package on or off, the indentation of the abstract section header changes on my pc. If it doesn't for you, I am not sure why,

Comment: Rien de tel chez moi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`titlesec` sets `\parindent` to `0pt` inside the section heading, so `\indent` introduces an indentation of `0pt` in your MWE. 
You can get the same effect by inserting a space of the same length manually using `\hspace`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xparse} 
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters

\NewDocumentEnvironment{ChapterAbstract}{}
{
    % Change the margins of the abstract relative to the regular text
    \begin{adjustwidth}{15pt}{15pt} 
    \nointerlineskip\leavevmode % Necessary addition due to the macro expansion of adjustwidth. Solves the 'missing item' error
    \section*{\hspace{15pt}\scshape\large abstract} % Smallcaps abstract title in \large fontsize with an indentation
    \itshape
}
{
    \end{adjustwidth}
}

\begin{document}


\chapter{Chapter title test here}
\begin{ChapterAbstract}
\blindtext
\end{ChapterAbstract}

\section{Test section}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks, this helped! So silly, I added \hspace{} in front of \section*{}, but that didn't work. Somehow I didn't think to try putting it inside the \section*{} command. Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: @tobyvd: You're welcome.